# react native i got an error in react-native-vector-icons like reject(@"font_load_failed", @"Font failed to load", error);

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react-native project. I included a module called `react-native-vector-icons`. Initially it does not give me any error and works fine. But now, i got an error like:

```
RNVectorIconsManager.m:95:37: error: too many arguments to block call, expected 1, have 3".Also,"reject(@"font_load_failed", @"Font failed to load", error);
```

Anyone, please please help as I am stuck with this problem. If I update the `podfile`, i got a warning like `React` has been deprecated. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Did you add the following code to your Podfile: `pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => 'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'` Please checkout: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-with-cocoapods

Comment: Added code formatting and also corrected the grammar to improve readability of the post.

Comment: yes i added this line

Comment: @karthick how did you resolve this?

Comment: i solved this problem by downgrading the react native version to 41.1.0

Comment: @karthick you don't need to downgrade react native, I fixed it by adding:

pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'  
pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

and removing the pod folder and running pod update

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved it with option: `react-native link`

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

method instead of CocoaPods, try to remove

```
 pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

From your podfile in ios/Podfile

And recompile your project

Answer (score 0):

I removed
    pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons
but not works.

I changed
    reject(@"font_load_failed", @"Font failed to load", error);
to
    reject(error);